# Does anyone know of a GUI library for the Io language

Tags: user-interface, programming-languages, iolanguage

**Io** is a nice cross-platform prototype-based object-oriented language.

Does anyone know of any GUI library for Io?

Io's name does not make it Google friendly.

Comment: One of the worst programming language names ever, google-wise, beating even C.

Comment: IO name is good, it is not IO's fault Google can't handle it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GTK+ Bindings for Io](http://www.quantumg.net/iogtk/)

Answer (score 9):

The 'official' GUI library is called `Flux` (formerly called Ion) and can be found in the main repository under

http://github.com/stevedekorte/io/tree/master/addons/Flux/

It is based on `OpenGL and thus platform independent (runs on any platform supporting OpenGL).

[edit]
Some examples on how to use `Flux` can be found in the samples directory:

http://github.com/stevedekorte/io/tree/master/addons/Flux/samples/

Some of them may not be working. Bug reports are welcome :-).
[/edit]

The `GTK+` Binding was created a while ago and is not maintained anymore as far as I know.
I would not recommend using it unless someone wants update it to compile with a current version and maintain it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1094855.1094916), there are:

> Io has bindings for many multiplatform
>   libraries including Sockets, OpenGL,
>   FreeType, PortAudio and others as well
>   as some modules for transparent
>   distributed objects and a user
>   interface toolkit written in Io.

Additionally, you can use Cocoa through the objective C bindings, and the languages author was at one time working on an openGL based interface called [Ion](http://osdir.com/ml/lang.io/2004-01/msg00192.html). I have seen the words 'IoDesktop' thrown around a lot too.

Comment: `IoDesktop`, `IoServer` and the third binary don't exist anymore since at least 2007. There is only one binary called `io` now which can load addons.

The OpenGL based interface addon `Ion` has been renamed to `Flux`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://osdir.com/ml/lang.io/2004-01/msg00192.html), you can use GNUstep on linux and OSX. I have played with GNUstep for a few hours some day and found it rather pleasant.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.iolanguage.com/blog/blog.cgi?do=item&id=107) there is a library for [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) bindings. Also I noticed IO library for GTK+ in their [projects list](http://iolanguage.com/community/projects/) but [the link](http://rtfm.insomnia.org/~qg/iogtk/) seems to be dead.

*If you are able to reach that (dead) page, please share it here.*